# Use one qtip to multiple places but with diffrent content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, qtip

**Hi,**

I am using [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) on my site and this is how the document ready function looks like :

```
    $.fn.qtip.styles.mystyle = { // Last part is the name of the style
       width: 200,
       background: '#ebf1ff',
       color: 'black',
       textAlign: 'center',
       border: {
          width: 1,
          radius: 4,
          color: '#AACCEE'
       },
       tip: 'bottomLeft',
       name: 'dark'
    }



   $('.controlTitleContainer .icon').qtip({
       content: $(this).find('.tooltip').html(),
        position: {
              corner: {
                 target: 'topRight',
                 tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
              }
           },
       style: 'mystyle'
    });
```

The first part is only for styling, the second part however is the one that will populate the qtip.

My HTML looks like this :

```
 <div class="controlTitleContainer">
      <div class="text">
           <label for="ModelViewAd_Title">Titel</label>
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
           &nbsp;<div class="toolTip">MyToolTipTest</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

*note : the class toolTip is set to Display : none, and the class="icon" div vill be the one that shows the tooltip*

I will have alot of html snippets like this on a page but it will contain diffrent data, what I need is the tooltip to show the current inner html of . Is this possible or do I have to generate a declaration of qtip for every HTML snippet like this?

Pleas Advice

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not have it like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($(".tooltip"), function(i,val){
        $.fn.qtip.styles.mystyle = { 
           width: 50,
           background: '#ebf1ff',
           color: 'black',
           textAlign: 'center',
           border: {
              width: 1,
              radius: 4,
              color: '#AACCEE'
           },
           tip: 'bottomLeft',
           name: 'dark'
        }

        var theContent = $(val).html();
        $(val).qtip({
            content: theContent,
             position: {
                      corner: {
                         target: 'topRight',
                         tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
                      }
                   },
               style: 'mystyle'
        });
    });
});
```

This way, any `div` with `class="tooltip"` will automatically have qTip enabled. That's actually what I did on my project.

Here's my test HTML:-

```
 <div class="controlTitleContainer">
      <div class="text">
           <label for="ModelViewAd_Title">Titel</label>
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
           &nbsp;<span class="tooltip">MyToolTipTest</span>
           &nbsp;<span class="tooltip">MyToolTipTest2</span>
           &nbsp;<span class="tooltip">MyToolTipTest3</span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have tried that and I get B.content is null ? If i replace the "$(this).html()" with 'test' then I can see that the tooltip is working. Is there somthing wrong with my HTML?

Comment: By the way, the word `tooltip` is case sensitive. Make sure your div has `tooltip` instead of `toolTip`.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that too, but I do still get the B.content is null? Also how do you hide the text in the .tooltip div element but show the question icon?

Comment: @SnowJim: I have a made a change to my post above, try that. I replaced `$(this)` with `$(".tooltip")` and it works for me.

Comment: My last fix... see the updated post above. This works fine now.